# Find duplicates for mixed type values in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, pickle

I would like to recognize and group duplicates values in a dictionary. To do this I build a pseudo-hash (better read *signature*) of my data set as follow:

```
from pickle import dumps
taxonomy = {}
binder = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in ds.items():
    signature = dumps(value)
    taxonomy[signature] = value
    binder[signature].append(key)
```

For a concrete use-case see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568962/group-similar-dict-entries-as-a-tuple-of-keys).

Unfortunately I realized that if the following statement is `True`:

```
>>> ds['key1'] == ds['key2']
True
```

This one is not always `True` anymore:

```
>>> dumps(ds['key1']) == dumps(ds['key2'])
False
```

I notice the key order on the dumped output differ for both dict. If I *copy*/*paste* the output of `ds['key1']` and `ds['key2']` into new dictionaries I can make the comparison successful.

As an overkill alternative I could traverse my dataset recursively and replace `dict` instances with `OrderedDict`:

```
import copy
def faithfulrepr(od):
    od = od.deepcopy(od)
    if isinstance(od, collections.Mapping):
        res = collections.OrderedDict()
        for k, v in sorted(od.items()):
            res[k] = faithfulrepr(v)
        return repr(res)
    if isinstance(od, list):
        for i, v in enumerate(od):
            od[i] = faithfulrepr(v)
        return repr(od)
    return repr(od)

>>> faithfulrepr(ds['key1']) == faithfulrepr(ds['key2'])
True
```

I am worried about this naive approach because I do not know whether I cover all the possible situations.

What other (generic) alternative can I use?

Comment: So you want the `repr` of each `dict` to be the same... any reason you can't just `loads` them and compare?

Comment: Well, yes using `repr` could be much easier than using `pickle`. Unfortunately the `repr` objects is not always enough to compare the content of two instances. That said `repr(ds['key1']) == repr(ds['key2'])` also returns `False`...

Comment: What I meant was - you want some *representation* of `dict` objects to compare equal - be it JSON/pickled/`str`'d/`repr`'d etc... Why not just reverse that and compare again? eg: `loads(dumps(ds['key1'])) == loads(dumps(ds['key2']))` ?

Comment: If you look at my example near `binder[signature].append(key)`, I don't really compare my dicts like `a == b`. So your solution does not work in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is to remove the call to `deepcopy` which is your bottleneck here:

```
def faithfulrepr(ds):
    if isinstance(ds, collections.Mapping):
        res = collections.OrderedDict(
            (k, faithfulrepr(v)) for k, v in sorted(ds.items())
        )
    elif isinstance(ds, list):
        res = [faithfulrepr(v) for v in ds]
    else:
        res = ds
    return repr(res)
```

However `sorted` and `repr` have their drawbacks:

1. you can't trully compare custom types;
2. you can't use mappings with different types of keys.

So the second thing is to get rid of `faithfulrepr` and compare objects with `__eq__`:

```
binder, values = [], []
for key, value in ds.items():
    try:
        index = values.index(value)
    except ValueError:
        values.append(value)
        binder.append([key])
    else:
        binder[index].append(key)
grouped = dict(zip(map(tuple, binder), values))
```